# Is it possible to add C11 support to Xcode 4.6?

Tags: c, xcode4.6, c11

I'm just wondering if there's a plugin allowing support of C11 in Xcode 4.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get gcc 4.7 installed underneath it, it has support for -std=c11.